# CSS - Position absolute differs from Chrome/Opera to Firefox/IE

Tags: css, position

I am newbie on CSS, and getting crazy with this!! Please, can some CSS expert tell me why this tooltip window is showed in different position from Chrome/Opera to Firefox/IE: http://jsfiddle.net/73F7w/1/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><body>
<div id="body_cont_actv">
  <form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="pg.asp?d=active&s=2" accept-charset="utf-8" style="width:284px; margin-top:20px;">
    <div id="frmdv">
      <div class="newrow">
        <label for="user">
          <span class="requ">Username:</span>
          <input type="text" name="user" value="" maxlength="15" style="width:226px; text-transform:lowercase;">
        </label>
        <a href="#" class="tooltip">
          <img src="images/help.gif" class="help">
          <span>
            <strong>Username</strong><br>
            Allowed only small letters and numbers. Max 15 chars.
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="newrow">
        <label for="pswd">
          <span class="requ">Password:</span>
          <input type="password" name="pswd" value="" maxlength="15" style="width:102px; text-transform:lowercase;">
        </label>
        <label for="conf">
          <span class="requ">Check Password:</span>
          <input type="password" name="conf" value="" maxlength="15" style="width:102px; text-transform:lowercase;">
        </label>
       <a href="#" class="tooltip">
          <img src="images/help.gif" class="help">
          <span>
            <strong>Password</strong><br>
            Allowed only small letters and numbers. Max 15 chars.
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
      <input type="submit" name="send" value="Confirm">
      <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear">
    </div>
  </form>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    document.form.user.focus();
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#form { padding:0; margin:0 auto; }
#form label { float:left; padding:0; margin:0 6px 0 6px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#form label span { display: block; margin-left:2px; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; color:#5C5C5C; }
#form label span.requ { background-image:url(../images/required.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:right 5px; }
#form input { border:1px solid #939393; border-radius:6px; font-size:14px; background-color:#F8F8F8; }
#form input[type="text"] { padding:4px; color:#0067CE; }
#form input[type="password"] { padding:4px; color:#0067CE; }
#form input[type="checkbox"] { padding:0; margin-right:2px; position:relative; vertical-align:-2px; cursor:pointer; }
#form input[type="submit"] { width:100px; height:28px; padding:0; margin:0 5px 0 5px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #0062C4; border-radius:6px; background-color:#00A0DD; cursor:pointer; }
#form input[type="reset"]  { width:100px; height:28px; padding:0; margin:0 5px 0 5px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #707070; border-radius:6px; background-color:#9F9F9F; cursor:pointer; }
#form select { padding:3px; color:#0067CE; border:1px solid #939393; border-radius:6px; background-color:#F8F8F8; cursor:pointer; }
#form textarea { padding:4px; font:normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#0067CE; border:1px solid #939393; border-radius:6px; background-color:#F8F8F8; }
#form .error { border:1px solid #FF2E13; }
#form .newrow { display:inline-block; margin:5px 0 5px 0; }
#form #reqmsg { clear:both; padding-top:16px; margin:0; font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#5C5C5C; text-align:center; }
#form #buttons { padding:0; margin-top:22px; text-align:center; }

#body_cont_actv img.help { width:26px; height:26px; border:0px; margin-top:16px; margin-left:4px; }
#body_cont_actv a.tooltip { outline:none; font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:16px; text-align:justify; color:#5C5C5C; cursor:help; }
#body_cont_actv a.tooltip span { display:none; width:160px; padding:12px; margin-top:-44px; margin-left:284px; border:1px solid #DCA; border-radius:6px; background:#FFFAF0; }
#body_cont_actv a.tooltip:hover span { position:absolute; display:inline; }
#body_cont_actv a.tooltip strong { display:inline-block; margin-bottom:4px; }
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are [copying the code](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/) than atleast do it correctly..

Comment: Sorry not add the source. I got this code from here: http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip

Comment: Wherever you get it, copy paste it correctly and debug

Comment: Mr. Alien, I did it. But in my page the tooltip is placed with other CSS code, and probably this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching "moz" for mozilla and "webkit" for Chrome...

Maybe you can make some screenshots?

Comment: I just need the tooltip to be showed in the same place (position), on Chrome and Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: I can't test it because I have only Mozzila..But as I said,if you get different results on Chrome and Mozilla,you should use "moz" or "webkit" on your css...here is some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit

Comment: AdiCrainic, I did it using your tip. Thank you!