# What is the difference between keyframes and webkit keyframes?

Tags: css, html, web-services, css-animations

The CSS I am using is like this:
I am not understanding the difference between @keyframes and @webkit-keyframes.

```css
@keyframes slideDown {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }  
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
   
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Actually you only need the first one ... and the webkit version is the a vendor prefixes used for support cases, search about it and you will get more information  https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110510/why-doesnt-css-feature-work-in-browser-but-works-in-others?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you add a "@webkit" prefix , you basically are allowing support for chrome browser to render animation.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718399/what-is-the-difference-between-webkit-and-moz)