# What are the most common CSS property prefixes?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I've been reading many articles and I've seen prefixes such as `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-`, `-o-`. Obviously the first two are commonly used and are also specified in W3C, however what about the latter ? Are they real, and if so, should I be worried about using them ?

Most of the websites only specify the need to use `-webkit-` and `-moz-` on specific properties which I'm aware of, however I am aiming to have my code cover the largest range of browsers possible therefore I need to know if the above prefixes and their inexistence can affect my cross-browser compatibility.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer over on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to create a Cross-Platform webpage (You MUST always do that) you will have to add all of them into certain CSS3 properties. Each one of them, represents a different render Engine.

`-webkit-` Used for Safari and Chromium browsers

`-moz-` Used for Firefox

`-ms-` Used for Internet Explorer

`-o-` Used for Opera