# Chrome and Safari Scroll Bar not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I want to use the same scroll bar as I have implemented in **safari** and **chrome** but I am unable to see it on **Firefox** Browser.

How can I do this? I have referred this question of Firefox bug

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790

but was unable to trace what is wrong with my CSS, Please suggest me a way to do it.

What I have done for safari and Chrome is as follows :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
  border-radius: 10px;}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

Thanks a lot for your helps.

Comment: Something can't be a bug if there is no specification for it to follow. There is no such thing as *-scrollbar-* anything in CSS and Firefox, rightly, has chosen not to spend time on it. Allowing a web site to adjust the user's browser interface is one of the unwritten THOU SHALL NOT rules of web design and programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only using the webkit rendering engine (Chrome and Safari) 
Sadly though currently there is no -webkit-scrollbar for the -moz rendering engine.

Hope this helps

[Difference between rendering engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit)
[Custom CSS Scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Cheers,
Demetry