# what is moz-flex webkit-flex in css?

Tags: css

I got a code sample from internet. I use it and it works fine. But I dont understand the working of the code.

```
#header {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.3);
    height: 3.5em;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 3.5em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

What does moz-flex and webkit-flex stands for?

Thanks,
Sabarisri

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 5):

These are browser specific styles for webkit and mozilla browser engines as flex property is not a standard yet. 
A very nice and detailed explanation is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit).

Hope it helps!

Comment: To add to this, flexbox is standardized in all modern browsers except IE of course. IE 10 and 11 partially supports flexbox. So the only vendor prefix required for flexbox is `-ms-` for IE 10 only, oddly enough, IE 11 does not require a prefix despite it's partial support. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox