# Do I still need display: -webkit-flex; -moz-flex; -ms-flex; at 2021?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is only "display: flex" enough? Or should I put them all for cross-browser functionality?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I dont need them if I do not care about IE10.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox

Source-2: [what is moz-flex webkit-flex in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236740/what-is-moz-flex-webkit-flex-in-css#comment56216758_34236818)

The majority of issues with flexbox relate to the changes in the specification, as it has been developed, and the fact that many of us were attempting to use an experimental specification in production. If you are trying to ensure backwards compatibility with old versions of browsers, and in particular IE10 and 11, the Flexbugs site is a helpful resource. You will see that many of the listed bugs apply to old browser versions and are fixed in current browsers. Each of the bugs has a workaround listed — which can save you many hours of puzzling.

If you want to include very old browsers with flexbox support then you can include the vendor prefixes in your CSS in addition to the unprefixed version. **This is becoming less and less of a requirement today as support is widespread.**

```
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```