# add date and score to my tournament Bracket

Tags: html, css

I have a tournament bracket created with html and css I'm not able to add match date and the score every time I add something the design change
I will be really appreciate your help brother&sisters
we use the function   `display: -ms-flexbox; display: -ms-flex;` to create the brackets

I only added div for date and time but it changed everything
What I have currently:

```css
.playoff-table * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.playoff-table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-content {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  padding: 80px;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-tour {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-pair {
  position: relative;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-pair:before {
  content: 'Date';
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  right: -12px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-pair:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  right: -12px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-pair:nth-child(even):after {
  top: 28px;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-pair:nth-child(odd):after {
  bottom: 28px;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-pair-style {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: white;
  width: 160px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-group {
  padding-right: 11px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-group .playoff-table-pair-style:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-group:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  bottom: 29px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-group:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-left-player,
.playoff-table .playoff-table-right-player {
  min-height: 26px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-left-player {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-left-player:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 27px;
  left: -12px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-right-player {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-third-place {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-third-place .playoff-table-left-player:before {
  display: none;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-tour:first-child .playoff-table-group {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-tour:first-child .playoff-table-left-player:before {
  display: none;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-tour:last-child .playoff-table-group:after {
  display: none;
}

.playoff-table .playoff-table-tour:last-child .playoff-table-pair:after,
.playoff-table .playoff-table-tour:last-child .playoff-table-pair:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="playoff-table">
  <div class="playoff-table-content">
    <div class="playoff-table-tour">
      <div class="playoff-table-group">
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style ">

<div class='datetime'>  12h:30          12/12/2023</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">player1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;8</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">player2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">player3</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">player4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playoff-table-group">
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playoff-table-group">
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playoff-table-group">
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Player 16</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="playoff-table-tour">
      <div class="playoff-table-group">
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">PLAYER &nbsp;&nbsp; 5</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров &nbsp;&nbsp; 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="playoff-table-group">
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="playoff-table-tour">
      <div class="playoff-table-group">
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="playoff-table-tour">
      <div class="playoff-table-group">
        <div class="playoff-table-pair playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">winer</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playoff-table-third-place playoff-table-pair-style">
          <div class="playoff-table-left-player">Иванов</div>
          <div class="playoff-table-right-player">Сидоров</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="playoff-table-pair-style"> The Winner is : </div>
  <div class="playoff-table-pair-style"> Third Place IS : </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really difficult to just look at the code and guess the problem. Can you please edit the question and only provide the part of html and css which is causing the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much mandy8055 for your quiq response , i just want to add extra information like time and score but when i did that the design change , how can i share with you screenshot ??

Comment: Screenshot won't help either but just wanted to check what exactly are you looking for and the effort which did to solve your problem where it went wrong? Because actually the code that you provided is pretty long so if we can see the actual problem that is happening in your code, it'll help

Comment: Just add the extra information to the code and we'll see the problem ourselves. We don't write the whole thing for you if that's what you are asking.

Comment: I tried only to add extra div on bottom of evry bracket for time and score but it change every thing in my toutrnament bracket because of usage of  flex

Comment: `display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;` can perhaps just be `display: flex;` ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65648293/do-i-still-need-display-webkit-flex-moz-flex-ms-flex-at-2021

Comment: I created a snippet from the code wall you had so now perhaps update where in that wall you wish the change to apply - seems like a LOT of css FWIW

Comment: thank you .. ok i added what i want to appear without chnaging my bracket  check now

Comment: Please edit your question to specify/describe in detail how you DO wish it to appear now with that additional DIV

Comment: sorry i but already did that i just added the dive above the bracket but it changed the size and position of my bracket