# Why so many bootstrap warnings in my console?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have imported bootstrap and following are my includes; it works correctly in mozilla. However, in chrome it says this:

```
GET http://np.lexity.com/embed/YW/5eac58cc7afdade1c6dea905c5dc7617?id=af1b3d2a1d3a net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Here are my includes:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Prerna Matrimony</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="themes/1/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="themes/1/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

I have also downloaded the bootstrap files and stored in my project folder. However, it also gives the same problem; there are warnings like:

```
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-inner-spin-button'. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.


input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,


bootstrap.css (line 153, col 22)
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-search-cancel-button'. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.


input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,


bootstrap.css (line 163, col 22)
Unknown property '-moz-osx-font-smoothing'. Declaration dropped.


-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;


bootstrap.css (line 279, col 25)
Expected color but found 'auto'. Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'. Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'. Error in parsing value for 'outline'. Declaration dropped.


outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;


bootstrap.css (line 1110, col 15)
Expected end of value but found '\9 '. Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'. Declaration dropped.


margin-top: 1px \9;


bootstrap.css (line 2523, col 18)
Expected color but found 'auto'. Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'. Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'. Error in parsing value for 'outline'. Declaration dropped.


outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;


bootstrap.css (line 2541, col 15)
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.


.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {


bootstrap.css (line 2579, col 14)
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.


.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {


bootstrap.css (line 2582, col 15)
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-expand'. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.


.form-control::-ms-expand {


bootstrap.css (line 2585, col 15)
Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio'.


@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {


bootstrap.css (line 2605, col 19)
Expected end of value but found '\9 '. Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'. Declaration dropped.


margin-top: 4px \9;


bootstrap.css (line 2656, col 18)
Unknown property 'touch-action'. Declaration dropped.


touch-action: manipulation;


bootstrap.css (line 3016, col 18)
Unknown property 'user-select'. Declaration dropped.


user-select: none;


bootstrap.css (line 3021, col 21)
Expected color but found 'auto'. Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'. Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'. Error in parsing value for 'outline'. Declaration dropped.


outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;


bootstrap.css (line 3033, col 15)
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('. Error in parsing value for 'filter'. Declaration dropped.


filter: alpha(opacity=65);


bootstrap.css (line 3053, col 10)
Expected color but found '\9 '. Expected end of value but found '\9 '. Error in parsing value for 'border-top'. Declaration dropped.


border-top: 4px solid \9;
```

Comment: Its your chrome extension which is blocking the first script (GET http://np.lexity.com/embed/YW/5eac58cc7afdade1c6dea905c5dc7617?id=af1b3d2a1d3a net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)

Comment: @AmitJS94 I understood that.. I disabled AdBlocks extension for that. Since then it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
GET http://np.lexity.com/embed/YW/5eac58cc7afdade1c6dea905c5dc7617?id=af1b3d2a1d3a net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Are you using AdBlock or similar extension with Chrome? It looks like so, because your browser blocks HTTP requests to that domain.

About second part of your question. Is it Firefox's console log? If it is, Firefox is not able to process [another vendor prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit) except it's own.

Comment: Yes; its on the Firefox console log.

Comment: Should I ignore them.. ? What say?

Comment: should they be ignored? I'm not being able to deal with those warnings.

Comment: Yes, ignore those warnings