# Letter more in text in FF and IE

Tags: css

Why I have problem with text width in Firefox and IE, because, on slider I have caption and set overflow in Firefox and IE displays letter mor than Chrome.

`font-weight` is 300

https://jsfiddle.net/8j1qb3o9/

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000000, -1px -1px 3px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod lorem tempor incididunt eiusmod tempor ut labore incididunt lorem ipsum et consectetur verylongwordrighthere elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  consectetur adipiscing elitsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod lorem tempor incididunt eiusmod tempor ut labore incididunt lorem ipsum et consectetur verylongwordrighthere elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  consectetur adipiscing elitsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit am Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod lorem tempor incididunt eiusmod tempor ut labore incididunt lorem ipsum et consectetur verylongwordrighthere elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  consectetur adipiscing elitsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit am Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod lorem tempor incididunt eiusmod tempor ut labore incididunt lorem ipsum et consectetur verylongwordrighthere elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  consectetur adipiscing elitsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit am Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod lorem tempor incididunt eiusmod tempor ut labore incididunt lorem ipsum et consectetur verylongwordrighthere elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  consectetur adipiscing elitsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit am Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod lorem tempor incididunt eiusmod tempor ut labore incididunt lorem ipsum et consectetur verylongwordrighthere elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  consectetur adipiscing elitsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore lorem ipsum dolor sit am consectetur adipiscing
  elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.

</div>
```

Comment: Give me your code.

Comment: @KevinAartsen updated

Comment: You are only using Chrome/Safari (Webkit) specific CSS to achieve a trimming of that text. Maybe you can try to limit the width and height of the container some other way (e.g. using `width` and `height`) and see if the text is truncated properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
     -ms-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
     -moz-line-clamp: 2;
      -ms-line-clamp: 2;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000000, -1px -1px 3px #000000;
}
```

Notice how I added the -moz- and -ms- tag. -moz- is so you're able to use it in firefox and -ms- is for internet explorer internet explorer.

More info about -moz- -webkit- and -ms- here: [CSS What are -moz- and -webkit-?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit)

Comment: still same problem, letter more in Firefox

Comment: Also tested it in the safari browser for you and it works too :) @ml92

Comment: What isn't working exactly? take a look at this fiddle it works fine i tested it in all my browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/8j1qb3o9/1/

Comment: This is an internet explorer bug i think. I don't think its possible to solve this without a workaround.

Comment: this is problem in Firefox and Ie, not only in IE. FF also bugging.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360427/text-overflow-less-on-different-browsers/40360474#40360474 @ml92