# -webkit-appearance: none; not working for button

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

Using contact forms 7 on my Wordpress site development and I noticed the buttons were different for mobile devices, so after searching I found the solution of `-webkit-appearance: none;` which I applied to the element `input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit`.

The style has been applied because it shows up when I inspect the element, but nothing has changed on mobile devices.

Should I have applied it to a different element?

Comment: Doesn't webpack automatically add the other 2 properties for cross-browser compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this code instead :

```
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
}
```

Consider adding `!important` if it still not working.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. When I inspect the element it says 'appearance: none;' is an unknown property name. This works fine for mobile now apart from Chrome on mobile. Safari, Firefox and Opera Mini are fine.

Comment: @LucyS. it's normal to get this warning as this property works only on some browser that's why we write 3. each one target a specific browser and the other are invalid in it

Comment: @LucyS. it should work on chrome too, can you share your link ?

Comment: It is working now, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @LucyS. you're welcome ;) You can read more about why we use the same property in different ways here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit

Answer (score 3):

sorry for the super late answer.
The class seems to be correct indeed.
Temani's answer is also a good suggestion for wider browser compatibility.
However, sometimes, even being supported by browser like Safari, the use of the prefixed -webkit- has no effect.
So, I'm going to give you two answers:

1. For the case of a *submit input* -your case-, you can simply give the background and border properties you want and that will overwrite the browsers default css properties. **No need of the *appearance* property**. But you will probably need to define each status of the button including *:active* and *:hover*
2. For *Check boxes* and *radio buttons* a workaround to the problem is hiding the input with *visibility: hidden* and using *:before* and/or *:after* to create an alternative check or radio which will also need a *visibility: visible* property. You can use the *:checked:before* selector to apply different appearances to each status

**Note**: remember *:before* and *:after* associated to an *input* will only work in Chrome and Safari and only together with the property *appearance: none*

Hope this helps