# Button Elements are slipping out (chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button

Im working on a little project where I want to add a button which opens a menu. The button looks great on Firefox, but when I check on brave or chrome the button elements seem to slip out and I cant pinpoint what it is...

[Button on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pjsO.png)

[Button on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CObWY.png)

**This is the button with the elemens inside.**

```
<button id="add-menu">
        <img src="plus.png" height="40px" id="plus-minus-icon"><p>Add New Menu</p>
    </button>
```

**This is the CSS code, hope you can help me.**

```
#add-menu {
grid-area: 5 / 1 / 5 / 3;
height: 100%;
width: 80%;
background-color: #333333;
border-radius: 25px;
justify-self: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
border: 1px solid black;

z-index: 1;
}
#add-menu img {
margin-left: 5px;
}
#add-menu p {
color: white;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: on which version of chrome you have the issue?

Comment: I have chrome Version 80.0.3987.87

Comment: it seems okay on my chrome https://codepen.io/sumesh/pen/JjdjQWx

Comment: My button is in another div, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use **-webkit-** and **-moz-** to solve this problem.

Please take a look here: [what-are-moz-and-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/what-are-moz-and-webkit)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of some known issues with buttons, fieldset and some more when having display flex or grid. You can have a glimpse of this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements/40483475).

Maybe in newer versions of chrome they addressed this issue, this is why it looks fine to @sumeshsn1.

So, in order to solve this issue, wrap the button content on a span element and add the flex properties there:

```html
<button class="button">
  <span class="button__wrapper">
    <img class="button__image" aria-hidden="true" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-basic-icon-set-2/300/7-128.png">
    <span class="button__label">Add New Menu</span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Some notes:

- I remove the id and add classes instead, as this would help you maintaining your code and would enable you to use multiple buttons on your html while being a valid document (you are supposed to have only one id in the document).
- As the image purpose is just a visual hint for the button function, lets add an `aria-hidden=true` attribute to the image element.
- Remove inline styles (the height attribute you have on your image tag).

Now, let's review the CSS:

```css
.button {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.button__image {
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 40px;
}

.button__label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Some notes:

- Remove the `grid-aria` declarations, as this property only makes sense when using a `display: grid` element, which you don't.
- Remove the `z-index` as well, you need to mess with this property for your issue.

I also wrote this snippet using BEM. You might want to have a look at how this methodology works and how it can help you [here](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/).

You can find the updated pen [here](https://codepen.io/avcajaraville/pen/VwLYZeX).