# Removing the inner shadow on iOS inputs

Tags: css, ios, safari, background-image

I've been asked to update a WordPress theme from 2015 and I see that inputs, selects and textareas are styled with the following property:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)); /* Removing the inner shadow on iOS inputs */
```

As the inline comment says, this was apparently added for removing the inner shadow on iOS inputs. I don't own any iOS device and my question is, is this line necessary right now for the latest versions of Safari?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only for Saffari, webkit also works for chrome.
Check this: [What are -moz- and -webkit-?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/what-are-moz-and-webkit)
But that code doesn't remove anything.!